# Accessing Dynamic allocated element and array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
typedef struct myArrays
{
int id;
}MyArray;
```

When we allocate dynamic array like this: `MyArray * myArray = malloc(10 * sizeof (myArray) );`  then we access the memory location by using dot(.) operator like this : `myArray[0].myVar`, But when we make single element `MyArray * myArray = malloc( sizeof (myArray) )`; then we access its members by using arrow(->) like this  `myArray->myVar`.

> In first case of array allocation , myArray = malloc(10 * sizeof
>   (myArray) ), myArray[i] is pointing to ith element. So here also we
>   should use arrow while refering to its members like
>   (myArray[i]->myVar).

I know (myArray[i]->myVar) is wrong but please explain conceptually why it is wrong ?

Comment: Because you are not allocating an array of pointers.  Where is the definition of myArray?  Please show a complete, valid example.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: `(*X).Y` means the same as `X[0].Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got its reason.In case of array: `myArray[i].myVar` means `*(myArray + i).myVar` and In element case : `myArray->myVar` is also means `(*myArray).myVar`. So basically I can also use "`(*myArray).myVar`" in place of `myArray->myVar`. And I can also use `(myArray + i)->myVar` in place of `myArray[i].myVar`.

In Brief:

> myArray[i].myVar ==  (*(myArray + i)).myVar == (myArray + i)->myVar

and

> myArray->myVar == (*myArray).myVar

Comment: Due to precedence of operators myArray[i].myVar means ( *(myArray + I ) ).myVar That is you need to use one more pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned yourself if you have for example a declaration

```
struct A
{
    int x;
} *a = malloc( sizeof( struct A ) );
```

then you can write for example

```
a->x = 10;
```

or

```
( a + 0 )->x = 10;
```

It is the same as

```
( *a ).x = 10;
```

or

```
( *( a + 0 ) ).x = 10;
```

and it is the same as

```
a[0].x = 10;
```

You can consider a pointer to a single object as a pointer to the first element of an array containing only one element.

If you have an array of structures like

```
struct A
{
    int x;
} *a = malloc( 10 * sizeof( struct A ) );
```

you can write for example

```
int i = 5;

( a + i )->x = 10;
```

It is the same as

```
( *( a + i ) ).x = 10;
```

and it is the same as

```
a[i].x = 10;
```

The postfix expression with the subscript operator returns the lvalue of the pointed object.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Thus you can even write

```
0[a].x = 10;
```

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    struct A
    {
        int x;
    } *a = malloc( sizeof( struct A ) ); 

    0[a].x = 10;

    printf( "a->x = %d\n", a->x );

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You even added the nuance at the end! If you `#define h ++` then you can have a `h 0[a].x`... :)